# Referencing variable from one javascript file in another

Tags: javascript

I have two JS files where I would like to access the variable associated with my JS Object.

rates.js

```
var CAD = {
    USD : 1.2727,
    EUR : 1.54,
    CNY : 0.20,
    BTC : 45139.58
    CZK : 0.059,
    GBP : 1.7338,
    CHF : 1.4345,
    JPY : 0.0123,
    AUD : 0.9827,
    PLN : 0.3405,
    ZAR : 0.0839
}
var CHF = {
    USD : 0.8911,
    EUR : 1.0766,
    CNY : 0.14,
    BTC : 32154.03,
    CZK : 0.041,
    GBP : 1.2086,
    CHF : 1,
    JPY : 0.0086,
    AUD : 0.685,
    PLN : 0.2375,
    ZAR : 0.0584
}
```

Second file where I would like to store a value in a variable:

dropdown.js

```
if(getTicker == "AUDCAD" ){
            var price = CAD.USD;
            alert(price);
}
```

I have used the following lines in my html file in an effort to connect the two with no success.

```
    <script src="rates.js"></script>
    <script src="dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not using a server therefore I cannot make modules to import and export. Are there any other recommendations?

Comment: You can try attaching it into the global window object like so.

`window.CAD = {...`

And using it in `dropdown.js` as follows:

`var price = window.CAD.USD;`

Comment: There is syntax error, a comma is missing after CZK property of CAD object in rates.js. Add a comma and try again.

Comment: @Philip this worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: As @Philip suggest you can do it using global variable with `window`, but it is discouraged. Because because they can be accessed from ANY function and you risk having multiple functions trying to read from and write to the same variables. Please see the modern approach I mention in my answer. Although using global variable with `window` is a common practice(unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

There is a `type` attribute in `script` tag. So you can set `type` as `module` in your `dropdown.js` file and export `CAD & CHF` from `rates.js` file and use them how you want. Here is the example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="./dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**dropdown.js**

```
import { CAD } from './demo.js'

console.log(CAD) // CAD obj
```

**rates.js**

```
const CAD = {
  USD: 1.2727,
  EUR: 1.54,
  CNY: 0.2,
  BTC: 45139.58,
  CZK: 0.059,
  GBP: 1.7338,
  CHF: 1.4345,
  JPY: 0.0123,
  AUD: 0.9827,
  PLN: 0.3405,
  ZAR: 0.0839,
}

const CHF = {
  USD: 0.8911,
  EUR: 1.0766,
  CNY: 0.14,
  BTC: 32154.03,
  CZK: 0.041,
  GBP: 1.2086,
  CHF: 1,
  JPY: 0.0086,
  AUD: 0.685,
  PLN: 0.2375,
  ZAR: 0.0584,
}

export { CAD, CHF }
```